# Left join suggestion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to join multiple tables in SQL Server with a common column dates but I want to avoid repeating the values from the different tables when merge.

```
drop table if exists #d, #t1, #t2

create table #d  (DataDate date)
create table #t1 (DataDate date, Value1 float, Value2 float)
create table #t2 (DataDate date, Value3 float, Value4 float)

insert into #d values ('20181201'),('20181202'),('20181203')
insert into #t1 values 
    ('20181201', 3.14, 1.18),
    ('20181201', 3.135, 1.185),
    ('20181202', 3.15, 1.19),
    ('20181203', 3.16, 1.195)

insert into #t2 values 
    ('20181201', 4.14, 2.18),
    ('20181203', 4.15, 2.19),
    ('20181203', 4.1, 2.195)

select #d.DataDate,#t1.Value1,#t1.Value2,#t2.Value3,#t2.Value4
from #d
    left join #t1 on #d.DataDate = #t1.DataDate
    left join #t2 on #d.DataDate = #t2.DataDate
```

Actual Results

```
DataDate   Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4
12/1/2018  3.14    1.18    4.14    2.18
12/1/2018  3.135   1.185   4.14    2.18
12/2/2018  3.15    1.19    NULL    NULL
12/3/2018  3.16    1.195   4.15    2.19
12/3/2018  3.16    1.195   4.1     2.195
```

Desired Results

```
DataDate    Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4
12/1/2018   3.14    1.18    4.14    2.18
12/1/2018   3.135   1.185   NULL    NULL
12/2/2018   3.15    1.19    NULL    NULL
12/3/2018   3.16    1.195   4.15    2.19
12/3/2018   NULL    NULL    4.1     2.195
```

Comment: Use SELECT DISTINCT (your column name), other column..

Comment: Could you provide the script. Thank you!

Comment: Your desired results suggest you want show a row for every join, but that you only want to show the values the first time a given bit of data is displayed? Thats an unusual requirement... what are you actually doing with this data?

Comment: I don't really see the point in this but what I might do here is assign arbitrary row numbers and do a full outer join on date AND rownumber... For example, something like the following: `select datadate = coalesce(t1.datadate, t2.datadate), t1.value1, t1.value2, t2.value3, t2.value4 from (select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by datadate order by (select null)) from #t1) as t1 full join (select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by datadate order by (select null)) from #t2) as t2 on t2.datadate = t1.datadate and t2.rn = t1.rn;`

Comment: Hi Dale. I have an End User who want to consume data from multiple tables in Excel. He is requesting one table (sheet) combining all this data when the only field in common is the Date. He also wants to have NULLs for the unmatched fields. And I agree is a very unusual request.

Comment: OK, but when 2 rows match on date, which is the *correct* row to match?

Comment: Just the unique combination. Technically if you order by DataDate you will end up with a number of rows per date of the matching the rows of the table with more data for that date and you will have a unique list of fields per each table. ZLK solutions works like charm I just need to check performance. THANK YOU ZLK.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposed solution.
I have added a third table, just to demonstrate that this could be solved for N tables with a common column.

**Prepare demo data:**

```
/* Prepare demo objects */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #d, #t1, #t2
CREATE TABLE #d  (DataDate date)
CREATE TABLE #t1 (DataDate date, Value1 float, Value2 float)
CREATE TABLE #t2 (DataDate date, Value3 float, Value4 float)
CREATE TABLE #t3 (DataDate date, Value5 float, Value6 float)

/* Insert demo data */
INSERT INTO #d VALUES ('20181201'),('20181202'),('20181203')
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES 
    ('20181201', 3.14, 1.18),
    ('20181201', 3.135, 1.185),
    ('20181202', 3.15, 1.19),
    ('20181203', 3.16, 1.195)
INSERT INTO #t2 VALUES 
    ('20181201', 4.14, 2.18),
    ('20181203', 4.15, 2.19),
    ('20181203', 4.1, 2.195)
INSERT INTO #t3 VALUES 
    ('20181201', 3.14, 1.18),
    ('20181201', 3.135, 1.185),
    ('20181202', 3.16, 1.195)
```

**Proposed QUERY Solution:**

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(d.DataDate, t1.datadate, t2.datadate, t3.datadate) AS DataDate
    , t1.Value1
    , t1.Value2
    , t2.Value3
    , t2.Value4
    , t3.Value5
    , t3.Value6
FROM
    (SELECT
        *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DataDate ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM #d) AS d
FULL JOIN
    (SELECT
        *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DataDate ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM #t1) AS t1
    ON (t1.DataDate = d.DataDate AND t1.rn = d.rn)
FULL JOIN
    (SELECT
        *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY datadate ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM #t2) AS t2
    ON (t2.DataDate = d.DataDate AND t2.rn = d.rn)
    OR (t2.DataDate = t1.DataDate AND t2.rn = t1.rn)
FULL JOIN
    (SELECT
        *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY datadate ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM #t3) AS t3
    ON (t3.DataDate = d.DataDate AND t3.rn = d.rn)
    OR (t3.DataDate = t1.DataDate AND t3.rn = t1.rn)
    OR (t3.DataDate = t2.DataDate AND t3.rn = t2.rn)
ORDER BY DataDate;
```

Demo fiddle is posted on **db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cdbe09ee16e01491adacca4d52f10d24)**

**Results:**

```
DataDate            | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 | Value5 | Value6
:------------------ | -----: | -----: | -----: | -----: | -----: | -----:
01/12/2018 00:00:00 |   3.14 |   1.18 |   4.14 |   2.18 |   3.14 |   1.18
01/12/2018 00:00:00 |  3.135 |  1.185 |   null |   null |  3.135 |  1.185
02/12/2018 00:00:00 |   3.15 |   1.19 |   null |   null |   3.16 |  1.195
03/12/2018 00:00:00 |   3.16 |  1.195 |   4.15 |   2.19 |   null |   null
03/12/2018 00:00:00 |   null |   null |    4.1 |  2.195 |   null |   null
```

Note (optional):

You can greately improve performance by introducing indexes.
As a demo, I have added CLUSTERED INDEXES on DateData column and the preformance increase is significant.

```
/* Add to improve performance */
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_DataDate ON #d (DataDate);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_DataDate ON #t1 (DataDate);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_DataDate ON #t2 (DataDate);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_DataDate ON #t3 (DataDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use min if you want the min value (or max depending on what you're looking for) associated by date and t1.value1. Your example, the values are not duplicates so distinct will not work

```
select #d.DataDate,#t1.Value1,min(#t1.Value2),max(#t2.Value3),min(#t2.Value4)
from #d
    left join #t1 on #d.DataDate = #t1.DataDate
    left join #t2 on #d.DataDate = #t2.DataDate
group by 1,2
```

if there are exact duplicates that you want to remove then use the following

```
select distinct #d.DataDate,#t1.Value1,#t1.Value2,#t2.Value3,#t2.Value4
    from #d
        left join #t1 on #d.DataDate = #t1.DataDate
        left join #t2 on #d.DataDate = #t2.DataDate
```